# How to extract zipped files using vbscript

Tags: vbscript

I'm trying this code I've found to extract a zip file. But instead of unzipping, it creates a copy of the zip file.

`Dim oShell
Set oShell = WScript.CreateObject ("WScript.shell")
oShell.run """C:\Program Files\WinRar\WinRar.exe"" X ""C:\Temp\Temp.rar"" C:\Temp\Test"
Set oShell = Nothing`

**Your help is much appreciated, thanks!**

Answer (score 1):

Adding a "\" to mark an argument as a directory/folder explicitly is often mandatory:

> Examples to uncompress a folder:
>
> unrar x c:\yourfile.rar *.gif c:\extractfolder\
>
> extracts all *.gif files from yourfile.rar to c:\extractfolder\
>   (trailing backslash required) and restores the folder structure

(cf. [here](http://cects.com/using-the-winrar-command-line-tools-in-windows/))

VBScript example for this principle:

> ... destination ends with a path separator (), it is assumed that
>   destination is an existing folder in which to copy matching files

(cf. [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/e1wf9e7w(v=vs.84).aspx))

Comment: I have another concern about the error that the file is not specified. here is the code

sSource = "D:\Source"
sData = "D:\Source\Data"
sZipFile = "D:\Source\Data\sample.zip"
wshell.currentdirectory = sData
wshell.Run  sSource & "\paext -o -p " & sData & " " & sZipFile, 0, True